# Cannot clone box64

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I want to install box64 on my raspberry pi 4b but i always get this "not found" message although this repo is available. Anyone knows why? (OS: 64 Bit Raspberry Lite)

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ git clone https://github.com/ptitSeb/box64.git
Cloning into 'box64'...
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 1: 2526fc26bdbcb46c18435ed08: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 2: Description-en:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 3: library: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 4: be: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 6: Package:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 7: Description-md5:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 8: Description-en:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 9: library: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 10: be: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 12: Package:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 13: Description-md5:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 14: Description-en:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 15: FFmpeg: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 16: mux,: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 17: machines: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 18: cutting: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 20: This: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 21: contains: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 22: and: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 24: The: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 25: to: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 26: codecs: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 28: This: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 30: Package:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 31: Description-md5:: not found
/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: 32: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Works for me on MacOS. The error looks like `/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https` was executed somehow, but wasn't really an executable or script. Can you check that file?

Comment: like what @Robert says, you may just execute `$ /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https` to see if git-remote-https is broken due to some broken libraries. Trying to reinstall the packages like libcurl3 may help.